# Is there a command line tool like bx to bitcoin that I can use with cryptographs

Tags: mnemonic-seed, viewkey, monerod-commands, spend-key

I would like to generate key pairs from seeds manually.

However, Monero uses several special methods like Keccak hash function or CRC32 etc., which bx does not provide...

Is there a command line tool provides functions that I can use with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Monero uses several special methods like Keccak hash function or CRC32 etc

There is nothing particularly special w.r.t. Monero's usage of Keccak or CRC32.

> Is there a command line tool like bx to bitcoin ... I would like to generate key pairs from seeds manually.

I'm not familiar with `bx`, but the official `monero-wallet-cli` can be used to convert a seed phrase into a wallet file, a keys file (private view and spend keys) and a Monero address (public view and spend keys). For example:

```
monero-wallet-cli --restore-from-seed --generate-new-wallet new-filename \
    --electrum-seed "your seed words..." \
    --mnemonic-language English \
    --password "some optional new password" \
    --restore-date `date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
```

Or to get the seed words etc for a given key:

```
monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-spend-key new-filename \
    --mnemonic-language English \
    --password "some optional new password" \
    --restore-date `date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
```

There are also various implementations floating around to create addresses/seeds, such as https://xmr.llcoins.net/ and you can use various tools to create valid ed25519 keys, such as `openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519`.